# UIButton dynamic font size

Tags: ios, objective-c, font-size, ios-autolayout

[image: Demonstration Image]

The image shows a 3x3 grid which is a vertical stackview, which contains 3 horizontal stackviews, which contain 3 buttons each. The top horizontal stackview has a correctly sized set of numbers within it(just by setting the font size to 80). The other two do not. 
I want the numbers to take up the same amount of space on all devices so every number on each button is the same relative size on every device. This must be done programmatically! Not in IB... I cant find much info on this topic so even a link would be helpful please.

Comment: Let' assume you are happy with 30pt on iPhone 6, which has 375 screen width. 30/375 = 0.08, so you can set button's font relatively to screen width: `UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width * CGFloat(0.08))`

Comment: Thanks.. I thought about doing something like that but assumed there may have been a more favourable way similar to how size classes work within IB but programmatically instead..